# Chrome HEAD request?

Tags: google-chrome, logging

Why does Chrome send a HEAD request? Example in logs:

```
2013-03-04 07:43:51 W3SVC7 NS1 GET /page.html 80 - *.*.*.* HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.22+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/25.0.1364.97+Safari/537.22

2013-03-04 07:43:51 W3SVC7 NS1 HEAD / - 80 - *.*.*.* HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.22+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/25.0.1364.97+Safari/537.22
```

I have a ban system, and this head request really annoying, and its happening exactly the same second with GET request.

What is the nature of it? any help appreciated.

p.s: I noticed that the head requests are all only to my homepage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) states:

```
9.4 HEAD

The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT
return a message-body in the response. The metainformation contained
in the HTTP headers in response to a HEAD request SHOULD be identical
to the information sent in response to a GET request. This method can
be used for obtaining metainformation about the entity implied by the
request without transferring the entity-body itself. This method is
often used for testing hypertext links for validity, accessibility,
and recent modification.

The response to a HEAD request MAY be cacheable in the sense that the
information contained in the response MAY be used to update a
previously cached entity from that resource. If the new field values
indicate that the cached entity differs from the current entity (as
would be indicated by a change in Content-Length, Content-MD5, ETag
or Last-Modified), then the cache MUST treat the cache entry as
stale.
```

Most likely it is trying to verify the clients cookie/session is valid with the server.

Comment: So I guess the server side code is still executed when HEAD request is sent? Strange but it happens only with few people who visit the website out of thousand per day...

Comment: In essence, it should only change the cookie value if the session is changed. Because the request is happening on your root document `/` your cookie value is most likely set domain-wide. If your root page is dynamic, it might inform the client if the eTag value changes. (for caching). It is possible they are using a browser plugin like McAffee's SiteAdvisor that does its own request on your site.